# Error in the PH file for RAMAN and FTIR calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, td-dft

I am doing the Raman and FTIR calculations using quantum espresso, I ran the following codes

````
&CONTROL
  title='Compound 4:bulk:(Si 2)(Ca)(P 3)(O 14):hP(4):P3 (143):primitive:230.81', 
  calculation='scf', 
  pseudo_dir='./', 
  outdir='./tmp', 
  verbosity='high',
  tprnfor=.true., 
  tstress=.true., 
  forc_conv_thr=1.0d-4, 
  nstep=100,
/
&SYSTEM
  ibrav= 0, nat= 20, ntyp= 4, 
  occupations = 'smearing', smearing = 'gauss', degauss = 1.0d-2,
  ecutwfc = 50, ecutrho = 500,
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr = 1.0d-8
  mixing_beta = 0.7d0
/
&IONS
/
&CELL
  press_conv_thr=0.1
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
  Si     28.08550  Si.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Ca     40.07800  Ca.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
P      30.97376  P.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF

CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   4.7132930000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
  -2.3566465000  4.0818314735  0.0000000000
   0.0000000000  0.0000000000 11.9970890000

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
  Si  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
   O  0.3303280000  0.0650750000  0.0860850000
   O  0.9349250000  0.2652530000  0.0860850000
   O  0.7347470000  0.6696720000  0.0860850000
   P  0.6666670000  0.3333330000  0.1202050000
   O  0.6666670000  0.3333330000  0.2500000000
  Ca  0.6666670000  0.3333330000  0.3797950000
   O  0.3303280000  0.0650750000  0.4139150000
   O  0.9349250000  0.2652530000  0.4139150000
   O  0.7347470000  0.6696720000  0.4139150000
  Si  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.5000000000
   O  0.2652530000  0.3303280000  0.5860850000
   O  0.0650750000  0.7347470000  0.5860850000
   O  0.6696720000  0.9349250000  0.5860850000
   P  0.3333330000  0.6666670000  0.6202050000
   O  0.3333330000  0.6666670000  0.7500000000
   P  0.3333330000  0.6666670000  0.8797950000
   O  0.2652530000  0.3303280000  0.9139150000
   O  0.0650750000  0.7347470000  0.9139150000
   O  0.6696720000  0.9349250000  0.9139150000
K_POINTS {automatic}
  6 6 2 0 0 0```

 &INPUTPH
      tr2_ph = 1.0d-18,
      prefix = 'pwscf',
      outdir = './tmp',
      epsil = .true.,
      trans = .true.,
      lraman = .true.,
      fildyn = 'pwscf.dyn',
    /
    0.0 0.0 0.0



&INPUT
      fildyn = 'pwscf.dyn',
      asr = 'simple',
      q(1) = 1.0,        !to correct for LO-TO splitting
      q(2) = 0.0,
      q(3) = 0.0,
    /
````

However, these error messages appeared below.

```
Check: negative core charge=   -0.000001
     Reading collected, re-writing distributed wavefunctions

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine phq_readin (1):
     The phonon code with US-PP and raman or elop not yet available
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...


WARNING: Could not generate an xpmem segment id for this process'
address space.

The vader shared memory BTL will fall back on another single-copy
mechanism if one is available. This may result in lower performance.

  Local host: adagp04
  Error code: 1 (Operation not permitted)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[adagp04:250395] 15 more processes have sent help message help-btl-vader.txt / xpmem-make-failed
[adagp04:250395] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 9 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
with errorcode 1.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them
```

Does anyone know how to help me?